# JavaScript Event communication when propagating?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple markup of 2 DIV's. one inside the other

[image]

The green is nested under the red div.

Both have different  `onclick` handlers and when I click the green , the event bubbles up to the red  div and triggers its `onclick`.( as it should be).

However , When I click the green div  , I use the [event Data overload](http://api.jquery.com/on/#passing-data) :

```
$(".divGreen").on('click',{ name: "Karl"}, function (e)
                        {
                              alert('inner');
                        });
```

And I can  read the value  :

```
  $(".divGreen").on('click',{ name: "Karl"}, function (e)
                            {
                               //e.data.name....
                            });
```

But I **dont** want green handler function to read the data , but the **RED DIV** handler to read the data

I *could* do it with `stop propogation` on the green div and use *"[trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) a red click"* with the event data.   - but I don't want to.

so my question :

Is there any way ( *no global vars please*) that when the event bubbles , also the data will bubble ?

[**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/evewic/2/edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the target of the event remains the same as the event bubbles up, you can attach the data to `e.target.data` like so:

```
$(".divGreen").on('click',{ name: "Karl"}, function (e) {
    e.target.data = e.data;
});
```

You can then pick it up in the parent event:

```
$(".divRed").on('click', function (e) {
    alert(e.target.data.name); // alerts "Karl"
});
```